# Installing subversion without root permissions

Tags: unix, svn, makefile

I have a virtual Red hat 6.5 box and have to install svn 1.8.
I don't have root permissions.

Taking cue from 
https://superuser.com/questions/75887/installing-svn-without-root-access

I downloaded

```
http://www.trieuvan.com/apache/subversion/subversion-1.8.14.tar.gz
```

unpacked it and got the following:
total 2.1M

```
4.0K drwxr-xr-x.  6  4.0K Nov  3 11:04 ./
4.0K drwxr-xr-x.  3  4.0K Nov  3 10:59 ../
4.0K -rw-r--r--.  1  2.0K Mar 11  2013 aclocal.m4
8.0K -rwxr-xr-x.  1  7.5K Dec  8  2014 autogen.sh*
4.0K -rw-r--r--.  1    94 Feb 22  2010 BUGS
4.0K drwxr-xr-x.  6  4.0K Jul 27 01:04 build/
 40K -rw-r--r--.  1   39K Nov 19  2014 build.conf
640K -rw-r--r--.  1  638K Jul 27 01:04 build-outputs.mk
264K -rw-r--r--.  1  261K Jul 26 19:24 CHANGES
 16K -rw-r--r--.  1   14K Jan 26  2013 COMMITTERS
 24K -rw-r--r--.  1   22K Nov  3 11:00 config.log
4.0K -rwxr-xr-x.  1    81 Nov  3 11:00 config.nice*
824K -rwxr-xr-x.  1  822K Jul 27 01:04 configure*
 52K -rw-r--r--.  1   52K Feb 13  2015 configure.ac
4.0K drwxr-xr-x.  4  4.0K Jul 27 01:03 doc/
4.0K -rw-r--r--.  1    23 Jul 27 01:04 gen-make.opts
 12K -rwxr-xr-x.  1   11K Jan 21  2013 gen-make.py*
8.0K -rwxr-xr-x.  1  4.8K Dec  5  2014 get-deps.sh*
 64K -rw-r--r--.  1   62K Sep 27  2013 INSTALL
 16K -rw-r--r--.  1   15K Jul  5  2012 LICENSE
 40K -rw-r--r--.  1   37K Jul 26 20:23 Makefile.in
4.0K -rw-r--r--.  1   924 Mar 21  2015 NOTICE
4.0K -rw-r--r--.  1  2.3K Feb 10  2012 README
4.0K drwxr-xr-x. 33  4.0K Jul 27 01:04 subversion/
4.0K drwxr-xr-x. 14  4.0K Jul 27 01:03 tools/
 40K -rw-r--r--.  1   38K Jul 26 20:23 win-tests.py
```

Now I ran

```
./configure --prefix=$HOME
```

Last few lines of this output are:

```
checking for unistd.h... yes
configure: serf library configuration via pkg-config
checking for serf-2 library... no
checking for serf-1 library... no
checking was serf enabled... no

An appropriate version of serf could not be found, so libsvn_ra_serf
will not be built.  If you want to build libsvn_ra_serf, please
install serf 1.2.1 or newer.

configure: looking for apr_memcache as part of apr-util
checking apr_memcache.h usability... yes
checking apr_memcache.h presence... yes
checking for apr_memcache.h... yes
checking for apr_memcache_create in -laprutil-1... yes
checking for Apache module support via DSO through APXS... found at /usr/sbin/apxs
checking httpd version... recent enough
checking whether Apache version is compatible with APR version... yes
checking mod_dav version... acceptable
configure: checking sqlite library
checking sqlite amalgamation... no
checking sqlite amalgamation... no
checking sqlite3.h usability... yes
checking sqlite3.h presence... yes
checking for sqlite3.h... yes
checking sqlite library version (via header)... unsupported SQLite version
checking sqlite library version (via pkg-config)... none or unsupported 3.6.20
no

An appropriate version of sqlite could not be found.  We recommmend
3.7.15.1, but require at least 3.7.12.
Please either install a newer sqlite on this system

or

get the sqlite 3.7.15.1 amalgamation from:
    http://www.sqlite.org/sqlite-amalgamation-3071501.zip
unpack the archive using unzip and rename the resulting
directory to:
/usr/book/abc/app/svn/subversion-1.8.14/sqlite-amalgamation

configure: error: Subversion requires SQLite

make install
```

However instead of building i received the following message

```
make: *** No rule to make target `install'.  Stop.
```

Can someone clarify what I am missing here ?

Comment: Did `./configure` finish successfully or did it error?

Comment: updated the output of executing configure above

Comment: It tells you exactly what to do. You need to install sqlite first.

Comment: You need to install sqlite *and then* you need to configure your SVN build to tell it where to find the sqlite you installed.

Answer (score 0):

The output from `configure` is telling you what to do: installer a newer version of SQLite. The authors of Subversion anticipate this may be an issue, and discuss it in the INSTALL file.

http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/subversion/trunk/INSTALL

Relevant excerpts:

```
If you're just installing a Subversion client, the Subversion
team has created a script that downloads the minimal prerequisite
libraries (Apache Portable Runtime, Sqlite, and Zlib).  The script,
'get-deps.sh', is available in the same directory as this file.
When run, it will place 'apr', 'apr-util', 'serf', 'zlib', and
'sqlite-amalgamation' directories directly into your unpacked Subversion
distribution.  With the exception of sqlite-amalgamation, they will
still need to be configured, built and installed explicitly, and
Subversion's own configure script may need to be told where to find
them, if they were not installed in standard system locations.
```

---

```
12. SQLite  (REQUIRED)

Subversion requires SQLite version 3.7.12 or above.  You can meet this
dependency several ways:
  * Use an SQLite amalgamation file.
  * Specify an SQLite installation to use.
  * Let Subversion find an installed SQLite.

To use an SQLite-provided amalgamation, just drop sqlite3.c into
Subversion's sqlite-amalgamation/ directory, or point to it with the
--with-sqlite configure option.  This file also ships with the Subversion
dependencies distribution, or you can download it from SQLite:

    http://www.sqlite.org/download.html
```

So get SQLite, build it, and then tell Subversion's `configure` script where to find it using `--with-sqlite=<location>`.